# How is Azure Storage Tables implemented?

Tags: azure, computer-science, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm the type of developer that likes to understand the whole stack and viewing Azure Storage Tables as a black box makes me uncomfortable.

RDBMS is an entire field of study in Computer Science.  The components necessary to support ACID operations, query optimizations down to the details of B-trees to create indexes is essentially a well documented, solved problem.

Apache HBase and MongoDB are open source and Google has published multiple papers on BigTable, but I can't find anything on Microsoft's Azure Storage Tables, other than usage / developer documentation.   Has Microsoft published any details on the actual implementation (algorithms, data structures and infrastructure) behind Azure Storage Tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Azure Storage team presented a [paper](http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/11-calder-online.pdf) at SOSP11 describing the inner workings of the Azure Storage Service (including the Table Services).